# Setting button size

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm new in android. I struggle with a problem which is how to set buttons exactly next to each other, automaticly scalled, so there is no empty space on sides or between buttons on every device.

I was trying to solve that problem this way: Find method that returns screen (or parent?) width and height, then create 4 containers with width of 1/4 screen, and create buttons which 'fill parent'. If creating container isn't possible, I can create buttons with width of 1/4 screen.

Is there a method which returns screen or app size? Is it possible to set button's size in Java code?

Comment: How about using a [gridlayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridLayout.html) with 4 columns each set with width at 25%, then adding a button to each column?

Comment: Sounds like that would do. But I don't know how do I do this. Thanks for link, I'm gonna try. Could you just tell me how to set width as percentage?

Comment: You can use weight attrbute in LinearLayout, you don't need screen size method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can simply use LinearLayout like this:

```
<LinearLayout
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:orientation="horizontal">
   <Button
      android:id="+@id/btn1"
      android:layout_width="0dp"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:layout_weight="1"
      android:text="BUTTON 1"/>

   <Button
      android:id="+@id/btn2"
      android:layout_width="0dp"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:layout_weight="1"
      android:text="BUTTON 2"/>

   <Button
      android:id="+@id/btn3"
      android:layout_width="0dp"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:layout_weight="1"
      android:text="BUTTON 3"/>

   <Button
      android:id="+@id/btn4"
      android:layout_width="0dp"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:layout_weight="1"
      android:text="BUTTON 4"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

By this design your Button's height will match all of the screen. you can change their parent LinearLayout's height and put some other element under or above it

NOTE: according theme that you use for your app , may Button's Background change. so if you need flat background without any margin you need to use theme.holo.light or create your own background and set it for Button like this and set it as Buttton's background:

background.xml

```
<selector
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" >

    <item android:state_pressed="true" >
        <shape>
            <gradient
                android:startColor="#ffFDE234"
                android:endColor="#ffFDE234"
                android:angle="270"/>

        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape >
            <gradient
                android:startColor="#00000000"<!--transparent color as default color for Button's Background, you can change it-->
                android:endColor="#00000000"
                android:angle="270"/>

        </shape>
    </item>

</selector>
```

Comment: Thank you! I was not very specific so you tried to help me with deleting margins, which isn't really needed. Thatnks anyway. Anyway, could you tell me how to add new "lines" of buttons above or below? Is there such a possibility in linear layout or should I change to table layout?

Comment: you want some Button above or below these Buttons? if yes,you can do it with LinearLayout and table layout both.in LinearLayout you can sort its children in horizontal or vertical,if you want both horizontal and vertical you should use two LinearLayout inside each other or use Table layout or Grid layout. if you give me a image of your porpose I can help you more

Comment: Now that I understand the parent-children thing it's not really hard for me to do it. You already helped me enough!

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code to get screen's dimensions in pixel:

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
Point screen = new Point();
display.getSize(screen);
int width = screen.x;
int height = screen.y;
```

Beside this, for your problem instead of this code you can set your *Buttons* width to 0 and use *Button.weight* attribute it automatically shares space between your buttons.

Comment: Looks nice, but if I went this way, I also need to know how to set buttons size in Java code.

Comment: @Kuba better to use layout managers for positioning unless you absolutely can't

Comment: For your problem beside this code I suggest using weight attribute of Buttons

Comment: That's right my mind went too far instead of asking for the easiest solution.

Answer (score 0):

With a linearlayout, use this code in your xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Setting each of the buttons weights to 1 will mean they all occupy equal space

Answer (score 0):

Without empty space between Buttons:

[image]

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
android:orientation="horizontal">

<Button
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:text="Button1"
    android:layout_marginLeft="-5dip"
    android:layout_marginRight="-5dip"
    android:layout_weight="1"/>

<Button
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:text="Button2"
    android:layout_marginLeft="-5dip"
    android:layout_marginRight="-5dip"
    android:layout_weight="1"/>

<Button
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:text="Button3"
    android:layout_marginLeft="-5dip"
    android:layout_marginRight="-5dip"
    android:layout_weight="1"/>

<Button
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:text="Button4"
    android:layout_marginLeft="-5dip"
    android:layout_marginRight="-5dip"
    android:layout_weight="1"/>
```